# Automatic deploy not working when debuggin universal windows app

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app

For some reason, when I debug my Universal Windows App, the updates I make are not updated. It seems automatic deployment is not working.

If I manually deploy the app and then debug it, I can see the changes properly.

On the first attempt to run a new application, I get an error informing the application is not deployed.

I am using Windows 10 Mobile Emulator on Visual Studio 2015.

How can I fix that?

Thank you,

Igor.

Answer (score 3):

I figure it out.

Just go to Build->Configuration Manager and check deploy option for the desired project.

For some reason it was unchecked.

Comment: Thanks! Solved my problem too. Surprisingly hard to search for this answer!